# Change "returnUrl" before redirect in Controller

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I have the implementation of authentication using "returnUrl" on the URL to redirect users after they login to the system. For some special cases of business logic, I need to replace some parts in value of "returnUrl" on the URL:

1. Character "/" to be replaced with "`_1_`"
2. Character "&" to be replaced with "`_2_`"
3. Character "+" to be replaced with "`_3_`"

So, with the returnUrl=/product/detail/xxx+abc&xyz, the final value of returnUrl is "_1_product_1_detail_1_xxx_3_abc_2_xyz"

In the controller, I replace the "`_1_`", "`_2_`", "`_3_`" to the according characters as above. After calling "return Redirect("/product/detail/xxx+abc&xyz")", the browser redirects to "_1_product_1_detail_1_xxx_3_abc_2_xyz" that is completely wrong. I'm not sure why its not working although the URL I pass to Redirect(URL) method is correct. May anyone give me some advises?

The information of .NET:

1. .NET Framework 4.7.1
2. System.Web.Mvc 5.2.4

Thank you.

Comment: I dont get it. you change the return url by replacing characters and then find it weird that it return to that string? Can you show some controller code how you do the replacement and the redirect?

Comment: _1_product_1_detail_1_xxx_3_abc_2_xyz is your action method?

Comment: @VDWWD The login URL is "http://localhost/login?returnUrl=_1_product_1_detail_1_xxx_3_abc_2_xyz". When users login, the controller will process the parameter "returnUrl". "_1_product_1_detail_1_xxx_3_abc_2_xyz" to be  adjusted to "/product/detail/xxx+abc&xyz" and pass to "return Redirect()"